# Policy with Session variable

Tags: laravel, session-variables, laravel-blade, policy, laravel-facade

I want to create a policy which would not be linked to any model because I use external APIs in this sense so therefore I store the information in the Session example I have `Session::get('isAdmin')` but since that does not not working

I have used the two following code already without success

```
public function isAdmin(Session $session)
{
    if ($session->get) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and

```
public function isAdmin()
{
    if (Session::get('isAdmin')) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

`Session::get('isAdmin')` is an boolean

For the moment I just use it in my saw template blade and I do

```
@can('isAmin')
    <li class="nav-item @yield('user')"><a href="{{ url('/users/new') }}" class="nav-link"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-file-plus"><path d="M14 2H6a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v16a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V8z"></path><polyline points="14 2 14 8 20 8"></polyline><line x1="12" y1="18" x2="12" y2="12"></line><line x1="9" y1="15" x2="15" y2="15"></line></svg><span> Ajouter un Utilisateurs</span></a></li>
  @endcan
```

Comment: Welcome. Have you written policy class? How it is used in controller? From what class are these code blocks?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: You want to hide certain block on page for non-admin user? Have you tried `@if (\Session::get('isAdmin')) /** code */ @endif`?

Comment: it works but i was wondering how to do it with the policy

Comment: Did you check samples in [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization) of how blade directives look or being created and how to create policy?

Comment: For me it's pretty simple: just use `@if` directive. Even more, you should pass variable from controller `$isAdmin = \Session::has('isAdmin') && Session::get('isAdmin')` to not having class manipulation in blade file. I don't see the point having not made `@can('isAdmin')` compared to existing `@if('isAdmin')`. :/

Comment: I understand but in fact the HTML element that I want to hide is in the menu so for your solution to work it would be necessary that I pass to each function to control the variable isAdmin which is more tedious than doing directly  @if(\ Session::get ( 'isAdmin'))